# PHP if/else is not working as it should

Tags: php, if-statement

I have the following code:

```
if($value1 >= $value2){
    echo "Value 1 is greater or equal to value 2";
}else{
    echo "Something else";
}
```

The variables $value1 and $value2 are having their values from a database. The problem is that whenever this code run, it always echo the "Something else". Even if value1 is greater than value2.

Both of the variables are numbers. When I echo them:

```
echo $value1 . " and " . $value2;
```

I have the following result: `1300 and 500`

Does anyone know what is causing this problem?

Comment: That not possible. Please echo the `$value and $value2` before the if condition

Comment: I suspect that $value1 actually IS >= $value2. Are you comparing a string to a number?

Comment: Please run `var_dump($value1, $value2);` and post the result here

Comment: The values are not what you assume them to be.  If the only conclusion that you can possibly reach is that PHP itself is broken and you can't possibly have made a mistake then you're not going to get very far with your debugging.

Comment: It even work with string. I think `$value` might undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have the following result: 1300 and 500

Your values are string data, not numeric data.  They're just strings which happen to contain numeric characters.  And since the character `'1'` is "less than" the character `'5'`, the string `'1300'` is "less than" the string `'500'`.

Convert your strings to integers.  Something like:

```
if((int)$value1 >= (int)$value2)
```

or:

```
if(intval($value1) >= intval($value2)){
```

You could also store the numeric versions in variables of their own for later use as well, maybe include some error checking for the possibility of non-numeric strings, etc.  But ultimately don't assume a value is numeric just because it intuitively looks like a number.  Data types are important.

Comment: Simple as that... Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

> 

- main concept behind comparing between two or more values, is to make sure all values in same data type for numeric values we can type cast string values into their respected types (i.e int,decimal or float etc...).

  - for when we use less than "<" or greater than ">" operators most of the time values (i.e indexes etc) are in  integer data type. this is valid for all most common programming languages.